# How to measure the mass of alpha particle?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, mass, nuclear-physics, atomic-physics

I was reading the rutherford experiment of the $\alpha$ particles. where we conclude that the positive charge and mass are concentrated in the center of atoms. while concluding the above result we use the charge and mass of the $\alpha$ particle.

I am still wondering when we don't know about the nucleus size(before the experiment). how do we know that:

1. size of an $\alpha$ particle.
2. mass of an $\alpha$ particle.
3. charge of an $\alpha$ particle.

I know that we can measure that speed and charge-mass ratio of $\alpha$ particle by passing it through perpendicular electrical and magnetic fields. Is there any experiment from which we can know the exact mass and charge of $\alpha $ particle?

Do they know that $\alpha$ particular are helium nucleus?

Comment: The size did not matter. Rutherford's alphas did not "touch" the gold nuclei.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. In fact that was what Rutherford got the Nobel (chemistry!) prize for. He trapped alpha particles from radium decay and shows that they produced a gas which, when excited, gave off light with the same spectral lines as helium.
[https://web.lemoyne.edu/~giunta/ea/ROYDSann.HTML](https://web.lemoyne.edu/%7Egiunta/ea/ROYDSann.HTML)

Answer (score 2):

1. Charge of an alpha particle - This is really simple to detect even in the early times
2. Mass - Avogadro's Constant was discovered long before the Rutherford's experiment. You
   can easily find the mass of one atom/ion considering that the mass of an electron is
   nearly 0.
3. Size - The size of the helium atom can be easily found by diving the volume of 1mol of
   Helium gas by Avogadro's constant. Now since alpha particle is devoid of only 1 s-
   shell( which is very small in size) as compared to the Helium atom  both the sizes are
   approximately same.

Comment: That is not the way to get the size of molecules. And Avogadro's number was known, but not "long before".

Comment: The (linear) sizes of the helium atom and the alpha particle differ by few orders of magnitude.